# Threads in gtkmm

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, mutex, gtkmm

Could you please tell me or give me a good example on updating the same GUI component from multiple threads in gtkmm ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some examples here:

http://www.c-plusplus.de/forum/p816067